# What happens if you don't have enough money to repair?

Tags: xbox-360, world-of-tanks

After every match your tank get automatically repaired and ammunition refilled. If you don't have money and you did a bad game winning low credits resulting in having insufficient funds for the repairs... then you start with your tank bruised or with less shots?

Comment: From what I remember about the little bit I played on the PC version, eventually unless you invest into micro transactions, you will be in the negatives even if you have a great game.  Repairing, refueling, and refilling ammo will eventually make it so where even if you have a perfect game you will still come out of the game owing credits.

Comment: @Mkalafut This is possibly true if you're buying the "premium" ammo for credits instead of the micro-transaction currency. If you refrain from purchasing and using the premium ammo (which provides a greater armor pen than the standard AP rounds), you'll be able to come out on top credit-wise more often than not.

Comment: It's almost impossible to lose credits continuously at low tiers, you'd have to deliberately try to make it happen so it's not an issue that can occur in reality.

Comment: @Shaun you still have to pay credits for ammo, the ammo getting progressively more expensive as the tier of the gun goes up. So at higher tiers, if you shoot a lot, you might indeed burn through more credits in ammo than you earn, especially if you are a poor gunner and miss a lot (or just go in guns blazing at trees and walls for the heck of it).

Comment: @jwenting. Correct. Hence, why I said "you'll be able to come out on top credit-wise more often than not" and not "you'll always be able to come out on top credit-wise". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game won't let you enter a match with a damaged tank. It must be repaired before you can queue for battle with it again.

You can always get the tier 1 tank in each nation for free. If you happen to have those all damaged and can't repair any of them due to cost, you can "sell" them (for 0 credits) and get a new one.

Comment: Tier 1 tanks and guns are free to repair and rearm. Tier 2 guns on tier 1 tanks still cost though.